# What is the best way to keep a list of references to drawables?

Tags: android, drawable

Any user of my app can create a new "Subject" and select an icon for it (from an icon set I define/provide). There is an `ImageButton` that presents the currently selected icon or the default icon, and when a user clicks on it, a popup with a gridview in it opens, allowing the user to change that icon into whatever icon he finds nice.

To do that I need an array or a list of the icons available for selection in order to make a grid view out of them.

The best solution I can think of is creating a global array/list of strings referring to those icons, but I'm not sure how good of a solution it is.

Using a database is a bad option since it takes time to re-query every time I need to use an icon and it's not very efficient.

Another option would be to just get all of the drawables from a folder into an array, but then unwanted drawables may also be included.

So my question is what is really the best way of doing it?

Comment: singleton of SparseIntArray?

Answer (score 0):

I handled this in one of my apps by naming each icon and giving it a number. image1.png, image2.png etc

I then use this to retrieve the image I want.

```
public Drawable GetIcon(Context c, Integer ImageId) {
    return c.getResources().getDrawable(c.getResources().getIdentifier("image" + Integer.toString(ImageId), "drawable", c.getPackageName()));
}
```

This way I only ever need to know the index of the drawable I want.